# Why despite no error, the List View does not work?

Tags: python, django

I am not getting any error but my list view does not function. The detail view at the top with ID =1 is working fine. I change the ID numbers and can see the different posts. But when I go to the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/feed/, the detail view remains stuck whereas I should be seeing 3 posts vertically. It is almost as if the page is not refreshing,

Perhaps class-based views are better ways to do it, but for my own learning I want to know why this is not working.

```
def feed_detail_view(request, id = 1):
obj = Feed.objects.get(id=id)
#print(obj)
context = {
    "object" : obj,
}
return render(request, 'feeds/detail_view.html',context)

def feed_list_view(request):
queryset = Feed.objects.all()
context = {
    "object_list" : queryset
}
return render(request, 'feeds/list_view.html',context)

#code in my list_view html

{% for object in object_list %}
   {{object.content}} <br/>
   {{object.user}} <br/>
   {{object.timestamp|timesince}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The indentation isn't format.

Comment: In my actual code it is correctly formatted.

Comment: Can you please share the urls.py?

Comment: Also share the model and if possible execute it in the shell to double check that you have rows in the db: `Feed.objects.count()`

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue, This was happening because in the URLs'py I had two URL's (both for list and detail) as similar. You cannot have identical URL's.